# Use an Update Query in a Select If condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use an update query inside an if condition? Currently this is the query I'm using

```
| Time_In               |   Time_Out            |   Val1    |   Val2    |
| 2014-07-19 13:00:01   | 2014-07-19 15:00:00   |   5       |   15      |


SELECT

IF(`Time_In` >= CAST('13:00:01' AS time) AND `Time_Out` <= CAST('15:00:00' AS time),(Val11 * Val2), NULL) 


FROM table WHERE ID = '5'
```

What I'm hoping to do is when the time is between 13:00:01 and 15:00:00 instead of multiplying columns val1 and val2 it will just update a different column like

```
SELECT

IF(`Time_In` >= CAST('13:00:01' AS time) AND `Time_Out` <= CAST('15:00:00' AS time),
UPDATE SET TABLE Val3 = 10, NULL) 


FROM table WHERE ID = '5'
```

I tried it like this but got a syntax error.

How is the proper way and correct syntax to achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: You can't do both update and select.

Comment: There really is no way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
UPDATE table1
   SET val3 = CASE WHEN TIME(time_in)  >  '13:00:00' 
                    AND TIME(time_out) <= '15:00:00' THEN 10 ELSE NULL END
 WHERE id = 5
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07611/1)** demo

---

**UPDATE:**

> ... I was hoping for both select and update query ...

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `RETURNING` clause; therefore no you can't do both in the same query. But if you really need this you can implement it using a stored procedure like so

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_select(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
  UPDATE table1
     SET val3 = CASE WHEN TIME(time_in) > '13:00:00' AND TIME(time_out) <= '15:00:00' THEN 10 ELSE NULL END
   WHERE id = _id;
  SELECT val3 FROM table1 WHERE id = _id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it like so

```
CALL update_select(5);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2843/2)** demo

Comment: yea i tried it like this but i was hoping for both select and update query in an if condition but was told that i can't do both select and update

Comment: Sorry for the trouble but I chose to just use the first one you answered. Thank You